# TYPO3 Backend Website-Panel is looking strange and is not usable

Tags: typo3, panel, backend

our BE-website-panel is looking kind of strange.
And we can't use the filter or add-new-element functions which are shown.
(We are clicking through to the sites themselves)
I didn't find anything regarding this bug so here's a screenshot:

[backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEO6h.png)

Also here's a list of the extensions:
[extensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOL9G.png)

Comment: Any special extensions you have? Cleared the cache? OpCode cache?

Comment: Could you inspect this frame, to find out, which style settings are active and make such borders?

Comment: @Thomas: No, we created one extension as frontend template but other than that we deactivated most other extensions.

Comment: @jokumer: Here's the css: 
xtheme-t3skin-8…00027871.css:1
.x-panel {
    border-color: #A2AAB8;
}
xtheme-t3skin-8…00027871.css:1
.x-panel {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #A2AAB8;
}
backend-9b3cdb3…00026461.css:1
*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

Comment: What about cache? Browser plugins?

Comment: @Thomas: Just deactivated all my browser-plugins and it still persists.
I also flushed all caches via install-tool

Comment: Used another browser?

Comment: @Thomas: Yeah i used Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Edge all of them are looking the same.

Comment: Other backend user see this as well?

Comment: I see the `adminer` backend module, but you don't have it in your extension list?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes i logged in as one of the editors and they saw it aswell.
I got Adminer in the list it's the third one under Admin Tools.

Comment: This CSS you post is the default one. Can you have a look where the border-width is overwritten? Which CSS file adds this big borders?

Comment: @Thomas: xtheme-t3skin.css and backend.css

Comment: Yes, and which one manipulates the border-width? Is there a `border-width: 10px;` or anything?

Comment: @Thomas: all i see is "box-sizing: border-box" and "border-style: solid" to be honest.
I don't see any border-width explicitly set.

Comment: But you see the border. :) So, there must be any border-width set, otherwise your browsers go crazy.

Comment: @Thomas: i found one .typo3-pagetree-toppanel {
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
} (backend.css) 
 i guess it's an accumulation of a few 1-3px borders

but changing 1px->0px in the inspector doesn't change anything by the way

Comment: @Thomas: .x-panel {
    /* border-style: solid; */
    border-color: #A2AAB8;
} commenting border-style of .x-panel changes all the borders but the view is still broken since the topmenu is still unfolded

Comment: Just compared the TYPO3.CMS/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/Css/backend.css file from github with my own .css and i can't find any differences. something else must be broken.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, altough i can't tell you where the error originated.
I downloaded the typo3_src-8.7.2 source files and overrode all my files via ftp, because i compared the whole folder with phpstorm beforehand and some files were empty on my side.